Freeradius realms and users issue
I'm currently running freeradius (on v2.1.22, don't shoot me) with sql backend.
I need to accept *@randombroadband.co.uk and send an Access Accept.
I have defined the realm in proxy.conf as below:
realm randombroadband.co.uk {
    authhost = LOCAL
    nostrip
}

in my users file I have the following:
DEFAULT User-Name =~ "@randombroadband.co.uk"
        Auth-Type := Accept

In the logs we have the following
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host a.b.c.d port 61384, id=49, length=183
    User-Name = "moo@randombroadband.co.uk"
    User-Password = "moo"
    Service-Type = Framed-User
    Framed-Protocol = PPP
    Chargeable-User-Identity = ""
    Acct-Session-Id = "9277500"
    ERX-Dhcp-Mac-Addr = "abcd.0000.0001"
    NAS-Identifier = "LNS1"
    NAS-Port = 4095
    NAS-Port-Id = "-0/0/0.0"
    NAS-Port-Type = Ethernet
    ERX-Pppoe-Description = "pppoe ab:cd:00:00:00:01"
    NAS-IP-Address = a.b.c.d
# Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group authorize {...}
++[preprocess] returns ok
++[chap] returns noop
++[mschap] returns noop
++[digest] returns noop
[suffix] Looking up realm "randombroadband.co.uk" for User-Name = "moo@randombroadband.co.uk"
[suffix] Found realm "randombroadband.co.uk"
[suffix] Adding Realm = "randombroadband.co.uk"
[suffix] Authentication realm is LOCAL.
++[suffix] returns ok
[eap] No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
++[eap] returns noop
[files]     expand: %{User-Name} -> moo@randombroadband.co.uk
[files] users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 165
[files]     expand: %{User-Name} -> moo@randombroadband.co.uk
++[files] returns ok
[sql]   expand: %{User-Name} -> moo@randombroadband.co.uk
[sql] sql_set_user escaped user --> 'moo@randombroadband.co.uk'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserving sql socket id: 48
[sql]   expand: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radcheck           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY id -> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radcheck           WHERE username = 'moo@randombroadband.co.uk'           ORDER BY id
[sql]   expand: SELECT groupname           FROM radusergroup           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY priority -> SELECT groupname           FROM radusergroup           WHERE username = 'moo@randombroadband.co.uk'           ORDER BY priority
rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 48
[sql] User moo@randombroadband.co.uk not found
++[sql] returns notfound
++[expiration] returns noop
++[logintime] returns noop
[pap] WARNING! No "known good" password found for the user.  Authentication may fail because of this.
++[pap] returns noop
ERROR: No authenticate method (Auth-Type) found for the request: Rejecting the user
Failed to authenticate the user.

So it finds the realm and the user in the user file then seems to ignore the accept and decides to lookup the SQL table.  Is there any way to get it to stop that once it gets to the accept?
